# Java - Reading integer value after space

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read Integer value after I hit space but using scanner it only works after I press Enter. How can I make it read the integers after the white space?

This is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i< n; i++) {
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    list.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: You cannot, it works that way

Comment: It depends upon your terminal, not Java: the terminal may not even send the keystrokes to the program until you press enter.

Comment: Is there another way to read the characters that would allow me to do that?

Comment: Why are you creating a Scanner on each iteration??

Comment: You can also read your input as a String and then split and cast to numbers.

Comment: @the_storyteller this would work only in swing application,

Comment: You can do this if n represents the known number of values you want to scan for.  The problem is that you are assigning a new scanner inside the loop.  Try assigning it before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, it works that way `System.in` works that way, that buffer is flushed only upon pressing enter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there another way to read the characters that would allow me to do that?

Comment: Not within pure java.